# Can somebody walk me through what this question is trying to ask of me?

Tags: c, function, programming-languages, rules, recursive-descent

The following programming languages question seems really unclear and what it wants me to do is not obvious to me, could somebody help me to understand it?

The question:

Implement part of a recursive descent parser for a simple set of language rules. Use any programming language for the implementation; if it isn’t a common language, please make a note of which language it is in a comment. You should implement functions for each of the nonterminal symbols and, using the following rules that describe part of a C-like language.

```
<ifblock> --> if(<logic_expr>){<stmts>} [else {<stmts>}]

<logic_expr> --> <value> == <value> | <value> != <value>
```

You may assume the following functions:

- lex(), a lexical analyser which places a code for the next token in the global variable next token
- stmts()
- value()

Terminal symbols should be encoded with the following defined constants:

- CODE LP for ‘(’
- CODE RP for ‘)’
- CODE LB for ‘{’
- CODE RB for ‘{’
- CODE EQ for ‘==’
- CODE NEQ for ‘!=’
- CODE IF for ‘if’
- CODE ELSE for ‘else’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see: You are asked to write two functions

- `ifblock`
- `logic_expr`

as part of a recursive descent parser.

For the other non-terminal symbols, `stmts` and `value` you are allowed to assume the existence of pre-written functions by the same names.

How to write a recursive descent parser should have been discussed in the lectures and tutorials, so I assume you know how that works.

To get the next token from the input stream you can call `lex()` which returns a code, as listed in the codes for the terminal symbols. What you need to do is to implement the `ifblock` by requesting token codes by calling `lex()` and to evaluate and match those with the required tokens according to the language grammar. Note that the `else` part in the `ifblock` is optional according to the grammar.

To evaluate the logical expression of the `if` you need to step into a function `logic_expr`, which you are asked to write as well, which evaluates a logical expression as defined in the grammar. Again, you may assume that the function for the non-terminal `value` does already exist.

Comment: How would something like be implemented in python? What would be your language of choice?

Comment: @coderboy99, my language of choice would probably be C. I am no expert on python, but the principle remains the same. To evaluate the `if` expression, you call `lex()` for each terminal in the grammar and verify that the token is the one expected (otherwise, fail with synatx error, for instance). For each non-terminal descent into the corresponding function that evaluates that non-terminal (every non-terminal corresponds to a function by the same name). So, it is something like: call `lex()`, verify `IF`, call `lex()`, verify `LP`, call `logic_expr()`, call `lex()`, verify `RP` and so on.